# Upload a file to AWS S3 using C# without using AWS SDK

Tags: c#, sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sqlclr

I need to create a C# SQL CLR stored procedure to upload files (data exports) to AWS S3 buckets.  These files will generally be very small.
The AWS SDK cannot be installed on the SQL Servers and I am finding it difficult to find any information about how to accomplish this.

I am looking for some examples or documentation on how to accomplish uploading files without using the SDK.

My experience is mainly SQL, limited amount of C#.

Comment: While it is technically possible for SQL to make API calls (see [this](https://github.com/geral2/SQL-APIConsumer) project), I would not recommend it. Instead, look at the S3 REST API documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/Welcome.html) and start learning about [how to consume a REST API from C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client). Alternatively, and easier, question why you can't use the SDK provided by Amazon

Answer (score 1):

You can use Amazon S3 via a REST API: [Amazon S3 REST API Introduction](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/Welcome.html)

However, it can get a little complex, especially when providing Authentication signatures.